# Node package for non-CLI argument parsing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

There are many awesome command line argument parsers such as [Commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js), [Yargs](http://yargs.js.org/), and [Minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist). But is there any parser for much more ubiquitous arguments, a.k.a. optional function arguments?

When I leafed through source codes for major JS libraries, I always see something like:

```
// myfunc([name[, opts]][, callback])
myfunc = function(name, opts, cb) {
    if (typeof name == "function") {
        cb = name
        name = null
    }
    // else if (...)
    // ...
}
```

And if this is a boilerplate for optional arguments, I presume that there is a module for this. However, my hunt for it bore no fruit. I assume that if such parser exists, it will be something like:

```
parser = require("parser")
myfunc = function(name, opts, cb) {
    let {_name, _opts, _cb} = parser("[_name<string>[, _opts<object>]][, _cb<function>]", name, opts, cb)

    // happy coding!
}
```

Comment: That isn’t really “parsing”, and complex arrangement of optional arguments is poor design. Pass an object or pad with `undefined` instead, like how ES6 defaults work.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, if I change `name, opts, cb` to `...argv` then it will be parsing. But I'd avoid it for readability.

Comment: @Ryan The example is a fairly standard implementation. Check out node source code to see 100+ functions that take optional arguments at least as complex as shown above, which is inevitable as JS has no function overloading.  Each is followed by a dozen lines of conditionals, so a parser should be able to save many lines of codes imo.

Comment: I know it’s *common*. It doesn’t make it a good idea.